# Mariadb Invalidating the existing connections after password change

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb, wildfly

I have an application running which connects to Mariadb using some user test_user and password.
Now when the application is already up - it will have connections created already. In the meantime password of that test_user is changed. But still the application runs correctly and able to access DB. But if i restart the application it is not able to connect to the Mariadb with old password.
So my doubt is when - For already existing connections how can i force from mariadb side to reestablish the connection

Answer (score 0):

[KILL SOFT USER test_user](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/kill/) will kill all connections/queries for the `test_user`.

Comment: ok it works.  But is this behaviour okay from DB side? When does the existing connections will be made invalid from DB?

Comment: Added `SOFT` to the answer after realizing that `HARD` was default and probably excessive in most cases. Soft avoid the kind of corruption things that can occur. Provided queries on connections aren't in a critical section they can and will be killed off including closing the file descriptor associated with the connection. Future application queries on the connection will fail. The application will be required to reconnect.